# which auto-complete mode to use for writing English in Emacs

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, aquamacs

What's the best Emacs auto-complete mode to use for writing prose in English? My main requirement would be to automatically complete its best guess as to the MOST LIKELY match with a single keystroke, rather than forcing me to navigate and choose which completion to fill in.

So that for instance if I typed in DISADV and hit ESCAPE, it would automatically complete it to DISADVANTAGE since that's the most likely completion.

It would be even better if it could automatically complete it just from hitting SPACE, if and when there's only one possible completion.

Suggestions?

Comment: Have you used [auto-complete mode](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/)? I don't use it for writing prose, but it supports dictionary-based completion from any number of dictionary files, so you would just have to point it at a plain-text English dictionary file somewhere. Check out ["Completion by Dictionary"](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html#Completion_by_Dictionary) in the documentation.

Comment: @Paul-r sorry to bug you, but since your name is first on the list I thought I might ask if you could take a look at my edit and possibly re-open the question.   I do use quite a lot of English to comment my code, and I live in Emacs, so this would be really helpful.

Comment: There's this, it didn't work well, it was always changing correctly spelled words that were further back. http://superuser.com/questions/540942/is-it-possible-to-auto-correct-spelling-on-space-in-emacs

Comment: I use global-company-mode that is bundled with spaceemacs for the purpose. It works well for writing prose in English. When I type it provides possible options, I can type "TAB" to choose among the options, use "RETURN" to confirm the selection or use "ESC" to reject the sole completion. It tries to remember my recent writing so that my recent vocabulary would appear at the top.